Transform Table from horizontal to vertical in PQ
I can transform the below table from this

to this using formulas

, is it possible to do so with power query?
i can do it if it was one column only , so from this

to that

using pivot columns , but i cant do it with 2 columns ,is this possible?

Highlight name and role columns and then unpivot other columns. Delete the attribute column

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"name", type text}, {"role", type text}, {"asset1", type text}, {"asset2", type text}, {"asset3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"name", "role"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

